# How to display PDF in Mobile View in Angular 5 or 6 or 7?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular7

I want to Display Agreement PDF version in mobile view in angular 5,6,7 . Its should not open in new tab..

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframe for a native mobile pdf viewer
Or you can try some library like https://vadimdez.github.io/ng2-pdf-viewer/

Comment: what do you mean by object?

Comment: @Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<div *ngIf="innerHtml"
  [innerHtml]="innerHtml">
</div>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  public innerHtml: SafeHtml;
  constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
   public setInnerHtml(pdfurl: string) {
      this.innerHtml = this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(
        '<Object data=' + 'pdfurl' + '>' + '<p>Alternative text - include a link <a href=" ">to the PDF!</a></p>' + '</Object>');
    }
}

Comment: check this code...pdf is not showing in this...dont know why

Comment: @PankajGoel - Code gets more visibility when included in the question. Please use the edit link to add that code to your original question, then delete the comment.